# Javascript: Why object is not getting initialise on new api call however the string variable is?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bookshelf.js

I may be missing something basic as why is it happening.

`GET: example.com/users` 
//gives all data

`GET: example.com/users?status=1`
//gives data with status = 1

`GET:  example.com/users` // this does not work 
gives same data as pervious API condition with status=1

On third hit, `self.whereObj` is not initialising to default empty object instead it takes previous value of `{'status' = '1'}`, however `self.page` and `self.limit` is taking default value if no query parameter is provided in query string.

`example.com/users?limit=3`, // takes override to `3` form default value of `5`

`example.com/users` // `self.limit` takes default `5` and this works fine

**So my question is why the `self.limit` (simple string variable) is initialising however `self.whereObj` is not ?**

```
var Bookshelf = require('../../dbconfig').bookshelf;
Bookshelf.Collection = Bookshelf.Collection.extend({

    limit: 5,
    page: 1,
    whereObj: {}

    myFetch: function (query_params,expectedWhereFields) {
        var self = this;
        var whereObj = self.whereObj ; // this is not initializing
        // var whereObj = {};  this is initialising
        var page = self.page;
        var limit = self.limit; //this is not showing nay initialisation error

        for (var x in query_params) {
            if (expectedWhereFields.includes(x)) {
                whereObj[x] = query_params[x];
            }
            if (x === 'page') {
                page = query_params[x];  
            }
            if (x === 'limit') {
                limit = query_params[x];  
            }
        }
        var offset = (page - 1) * limit;

        function fetch() {
            return  self.constructor.forge()
                .query({where: whereObj})
                .query(function (qb) {
                    qb.offset(offset).limit(limit);
                })
                .then(function (collection) {
                    return collection;
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    return err
                });
        }
        return new fetch();
    }
});
module.exports = Bookshelf;
```

**UPDATED**

**service.js**

```
var Model = require('./../models/Users');
var express = require('express');

var listUsers = function (query_params, callback) {
    var expectedWhereFields = ["type", "status", "name"]; 
    Model.Users
        .forge()
        .myFetch(query_params, expectedWhereFields)      
        .then(function (collection) {
            return callback(null, collection);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            return callback(err, null);
        });
};

module.exports = {
    listUsers: listUsers
};
```

**model/Users.js**

```
var Bookshelf = require('../../dbconfig').bookshelf;
var Base = require('./base');

// Users model
var User = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'user_table'
});
var Users =  Bookshelf.Collection.extend({
    model: User
});

module.exports = {
    User: User,
    Users: Users
};
```

Comment: Is this Backbone?

Comment: No Nodejs (express).

Comment: even `self.limit` is not initializing, you are just calling the method `myFetch`, which does not initialize the object properties. simply do it with `var whereObj = {};`

Comment: but when I am doing `console.log(limit)` it is showing `5` (which is `self.limit`) on third hit , if I am not passing `limit=3` as parameter .

Comment: You should not be calling `fetch` with `new`. Actually you should not need to wrap it in a function at all. Also, `.then(function(collection) { return collection; })` is useless and can be omitted, and `.catch(function(err) { return err; })` is probably a mistake and should be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is why the `self.limit` (simple string variable) is initialising however `self.whereObj` is not?

Because objects are reference values. When you set `var whereObj = self.whereObj;`, both refer to the same object, and when you copy the query parameters into the object properties you are effectively writing into your defaults instance. This does not happen with primitive values such as strings - they don't have mutable properties.